# Input Boxes translateX

Tags: css, transition, translate-animation

I have two input boxes, one for Search and another for an email newsletter signup, in a slideout menu.

These are meant to slide out from the right when the menu is opened, along with the rest of the menu items.

I added the following css code to the menu items and the input boxes:

```
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
transform: translateX(10px);
```

And this is the css code for when the menu is opened:

```
opacity: 1;
transform: translateX(0px);
```

The rest of the menu items are sliding in from the right, but the input boxes aren't. I'm using the following class to the call the search form:

```
.shiftnav.shiftnav-shiftnav-main.shiftnav-open-target .grid-search .searchform .search-table .search-field input
```

I'm using the following class to call the email newsletter signup input:

```
.shiftnav.shiftnav-shiftnav-main.shiftnav-open-target form#mc4wp-form-1
```

Here's the HTML for the search:

```
      <div class="grid-search"><form role="search" class="searchform" method="get" action="http://test.unknowndesign.co.za/">
<div class="search-table">
    <div class="search-field">
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" class="s" placeholder="Search the site">
    </div>
    <div class="search-button">
        <input type="submit" class="searchsubmit" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the HTML for the Newsletter sign up form:

```
    <form id="mc4wp-form-1" class="mc4wp-form mc4wp-form-515" method="post" data-id="515" data-name="Newsletter"><div class="mc4wp-form-fields"><p>
<input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Sign up for our newsletter" required="">
```

Leave this field empty if you're human:

Comment: Do not share external sites. Make a working SO snippet with the relevant code that replicates your problem

Comment: @MihaiT Just thought of that now. Removed the external links. How can I make a working snippet?

Comment: when posting/editing you will see an icon in the top toolbar with `<>` symbol. ( near the image icon ) . Click it and then you can add html/css/javascript and make a working snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a basic example to slide in an input field. It adds a class to the form when the button is clicked, which triggers the animation. Hope this helps you.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(".searchform").toggleClass("opened");
});
```

```css
.grid-search {
padding: 10px 0 0 100px;
}
.searchform {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transform: translateX(10px);
}

.searchform.opened {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<div class="grid-search">
  <form role="search" class="searchform" method="get" action="http://test.unknowndesign.co.za/">
    <div class="search-table">
      <div class="search-field">
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" class="s" placeholder="Search the site">
      </div>
      <div class="search-button">
        <input type="submit" class="searchsubmit" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```